# Making the size of elements the same with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a function that is supposed to check the size of each element store the biggest size in a variable, then apply that size to all the elements. It seems to be working when the browser is refreshed but not when the window is resized. Here's my code;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function jobs_height() {
    var highest = 0;

    $(".jobs").each(function() {
      var job_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);

      if (job_height > highest) {
        highest = job_height;
      }
    });

    $(".jobs").css("height", highest);
  }

  //calling functions 
  $(window).ready(function() {
    jobs_height();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      jobs_height();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.jobs {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="jobs_cont">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="jobs">
        <h2 class="job_title">Construction Site<br>Supervisor role</h2>
        <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Site Supervisor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
        <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="jobs">
        <h2 class="job_title">Construction Contracts<br>Manager role</h2>
        <p class="salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
        <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Contracts Manager to their...<a href="#">See More</a></p>
        <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="jobs">
        <h2 class="job_title">Graduate Quantity<br>Surveyor role</h2>
        <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <p class="job_info">Our client a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add a Graduate Quantity Surveyor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
        <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/aLXjbz

UPDATE:

after trying Jameson the dog's and Simon's answers which both work I have encountered another problem. When I hard refresh i get this

[image: new issue]

as you can see the boxes are too small. but once I resize the window it works fine. Why is this happening?

UPDATE 2:

Ok so I figured out why it wasn't working on load. I was because I was using the wrong function to check when the page was loaded. What I should of been using is;

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    jobs_height();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think about in a flow manner.

first you set the height of all the elements to a *fixed* height.

then you try to query the elements height - **you will always get the same height you've set before!** (because it's fixed and "hard coded")

just add this line `$(".jobs").css("height", '');` in the start of `jobs_height()` to cancel your previous definition (it happens so fast you won't notice) and you're golden

***EDIT***

simon is right, once `document ready` is called `window ready` won't be called - so you should just call `jobs_height()` instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function jobs_height() {
    $(".jobs").css("height", '');
    var highest = 0;

    $(".jobs").each(function() {
      var job_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);

      if (job_height > highest) {
        highest = job_height;
      }
    });

    $(".jobs").css("height", highest);
  }

  //calling functions 
  jobs_height(); // call function instead of adding listener 
  $(window).resize(jobs_height);
 
});
```

```css
.jobs {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="jobs_cont">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="jobs">
        <h2 class="job_title">Construction Site<br>Supervisor role</h2>
        <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Site Supervisor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
        <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="jobs">
        <h2 class="job_title">Construction Contracts<br>Manager role</h2>
        <p class="salary">Salary: £40,000 – £45,000</p>
        <p class="job_info">Our client is a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add an experienced Construction Contracts Manager to their...<a href="#">See More</a></p>
        <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="jobs">
        <h2 class="job_title">Graduate Quantity<br>Surveyor role</h2>
        <p class="salary">Salary: £20,000 – £22,000</p>
        <p class="job_info">Our client a well-established and respected Building and Refurbishment company based in Leeds, are looking to add a Graduate Quantity Surveyor to their team. <a href="#">See More</a></p>
        <a href="#" class="red_button cv_button">SUBMIT CV</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the edit to my question if you have time. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks mate but I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

If you update the window functions so that there's only a single `window.resize` and set the height of each of the divs to auto before you get their `outerHeight()` then that should solve it.

Here's the updated function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function jobs_height(){

        var highest = 0;

        $(".jobs").each(function(){

            $(this).css('height','auto');
            var job_height = $(this).outerHeight();

            if(job_height > highest){
                highest = job_height;
            }

        });

        $(".jobs").css("height", highest);
    }

    //calling functions 
    $(window).resize(jobs_height);

});
```

This can be tested on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWGZqo)

Comment: Check the edit to my question if you have time. Thanks!

Comment: @Reece Try adding `$(window).trigger('resize');` or `$(window).resize();` just below the `$(window).resize(jobs_height);`. Not certain it'll solve it but it might. CodePen updated too.

Comment: Thanks mate but I figured it out